# How to include better bit mixer for unordered map C++14

Tags: c++, c++11, hashtable, c++14, unordered-map

How to incorporate the following bit mixing code in order to minimize the hash collisions inside the unordered_map? Intention is help the internal hashing scheme of unordered map to perform the bit mixer strategy for minimizing the hash collisions. Being a noob, I am unable to figure out as how to do it even after reading documentation.

```
UInt64 MurmurHash3Mixer( UInt64 key )
  {
  key ^= (key >> 33);
  key *= 0xff51afd7ed558ccd;
  key ^= (key >> 33);
  key *= 0xc4ceb9fe1a85ec53;
  key ^= (key >> 33);

  return key;
  }
```

Posted code was referred from the [site](https://zimbry.blogspot.com/2011/09/better-bit-mixing-improving-on.html).

Following is the full code (testing code) just to get 'MurmurHash3Mixer' included into the 'std::unordered_map' hashing scheme.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <unordered_map>

uint64_t MurmurHash3Mixer( uint64_t key ) { 
    key ^= (key >> 33);
    key *= 0xff51afd7ed558ccd;
    key ^= (key >> 33);
    key *= 0xc4ceb9fe1a85ec53;
    key ^= (key >> 33);

    return key;
}


int main() {

    uint64_t tx = 10L;
    std::unordered_map<uint64_t, uint64_t> ht; 
    ht.insert(std::make_pair<uint64_t, uint64_t>(tx, 20));
    std::cout << ht[tx] << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to set up a function object that accepts a const Key & and returns a size_t. Then you pass it as the template when you create the unordered map

```
struct myhash
{
   size_t operator() (const UInt64 &key)
   {
      return (size_t) MurmurHash3Mixer(key):
   }
}

std::unordered_map<uint64_t, uint64_t, myhash> ht;
```

Answer (score 0):

Just to add the corrected code, for folks with same issue.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <unordered_map>

uint64_t MurmurHash3Mixer( uint64_t key ) {
    key ^= (key >> 33);
    key *= 0xff51afd7ed558ccd;
    key ^= (key >> 33);
    key *= 0xc4ceb9fe1a85ec53;
    key ^= (key >> 33);

    return key;
}

struct myhash {
   std::size_t operator() (const uint64_t &key) const {
      return (size_t) MurmurHash3Mixer(key);
    }
};


int main() {

    uint64_t tx = 10L;
    std::unordered_map<uint64_t, uint64_t, myhash> ht;
    ht.insert(std::make_pair<uint64_t, uint64_t>(tx, 20));
    std::cout << ht[tx] << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```